# What is the number of degree $1$ representations of a finite group?

Tags: finite-groups, representation-theory, derived-subgroup

Let $G$ be a finite group and $G'$ be the derived subgroup of $G.$ Then I know that every degree $1$ representation of $G$ factors through $G/G'.$ How does it imply that the number of degree $1$ representations of $G$ is same as $\left \lvert G/G' \right \rvert\ $?

Would anybody please help me in this regard? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A general fact for finite groups is that they have a finite number of irreduicible representations and if the dimensions of these are $d_1,..., d_n$ then we have
$$d^2_1 + ... + d^2_n = |G|.$$
This is a consequence of Schur orthogonality relations among characters.

If $G$ is abelian, then all the irreducible reps are one dimensional and so the previous equation tells you $|G| = n$, the number of irreducible reps.

Now, in your context, $G/G'$ is abelian and as you say every 1 dimensional rep of $G$ corresponds, bijectively since you can always compose with the quotient, with those 1 -dimensional reps of $G/G'$, but his being abelian has $|G/G'|$ of those, by the argument above.

Comment: Oh! I see now. Given any degree $1$ representation of $G$ we have a representation of $G/G'$ and also given any irreducible representations of $G/G'$ we can get a degree $1$ representation of $G$ just by composing it with the projection from $G$ onto $G/G'.$ So the number of degree $1$ representations of $G$ is same as the number of irreducible representations of $G/G'.$ But $G/G'$ being abelian all the irreducible representations of it are of degree $1$ and hence by Schur's orthogonality relations it follows that the number of irreducible representations of $G/G'$ is same as $|G/G'|.$ Done!

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind help.

Comment: You can also use the classification of finite abelian groups to show every finite abelian group is isomorphic to its dual group (which consists of the 1D reps).